# MS Access - How to Add Items to List Box and Select only Items that are found in Recordset

Tags: ms-access, select, listbox, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a list box that is populated by a recordset. I am trying to then select the items in that list box based on the values in another recordset. I am able to populate the list box, but when I try to select the values based on another recordset the list box Me.ToolUsed1 is Null. I call another function for selecting the values because I plan on using the same procedure for other list boxes. I really appreciate any help that you can provide.

```
           'Populate the tool list box
            While Not rsToolList.EOF
                Me.ToolUsed1.AddItem Item:=rsToolList.Fields(0)
                rsToolList.MoveNext
            Wend

            matchKey = "MatchKey = """ & rsActivities.Fields(0) & """"

            If rsTools.RecordCount > 0 Then
                rsTools.MoveFirst
                rsTools.FindFirst (matchKey)

                toolIndex = rsTools.Fields(2)
                While Not rsTools.EOF
                    If (rsTools.Fields(2) = toolIndex) Then
                        SelectListValues Me.ToolUsed1, rsTools.Fields(1)
                    End If
                    rsTools.MoveNext
                Wend
            End If

Private Sub SelectListValues(tempListBox As Object, selectString As String)
Dim i As Integer
Dim found As Boolean

i = 0
found = False

 'select the value in the listbox
    While i < tempListBox.ListCount And Not found
      If tempListBox.Value(i) = selectString Then
          tempListBox.Selected(i) = True
          found = True
       End If
       i = i + 1
  Wend

  'if the string wasn't found, add it 
  If Not found Then
     tempListBox.AddItem (selectString)
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a query recordsource for your listbox instead of value items to add. Listboxes like comboxes maintain the [RowSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196460.aspx) property, allowing for Table/Query sources which you can set to the first recordset, `rsToolList`. Then, just open one recordset, `rsTools`, and loop through it to decide selected items. Do note, with table/query sources the bound column is the value of the listbox, not any of the other columns.

```
' POPULATE TOOL LIST BOX TO QUERY
Me.tempListBox.RowSource = "ToolList"       ' OR USE SELECT SQL STATEMENT HERE
Me.tempListBox.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Me.tempListBox.Requery

' LOOP THROUGH LISTBOX AND RECORDSET FOR SELECTED ITEMS 
Dim rsTools As Recordset, i As Integer

Set rsTools = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tools", dbOpenDynaset)

rsTools.MoveLast
rsTools.MoveFirst

If rsTools.RecordCount > 0 Then
    While Not rsTools.EOF
       i = 1
       While i < Me.tempListBox.ListCount
           ' CHANGE C FUNCTION HERE TO NEEDED TYPE: CLng, CInt, CStr, CDate, ...
           If CLng(Me.tempListBox.ItemData(i)) = rsTools.Fields(1) Then
               Me.tempListBox.Selected(i) = True
           End If
           i = i + 1
       Wend
       rsTools.MoveNext
    Wend
End If

rsTools.Close
Set rsTools = Nothing
```